# Problem with Firefox & IE8 not showing mouseover alt text for image maps

Tags: html, dictionary, tooltip, mouseover

I have the following HTML:

```
<div style="position: relative; text-align: left;">
<img id="chart_6c544b37_ac9d_49ed_912e_5ff8ad6c0181_BaseImage" src="chart.gif" width="460px" height="240px" usemap="#chart_6c544b37_ac9d_49ed_912e_5ff8ad6c0181" border="0">

<map name="chart_6c544b37_ac9d_49ed_912e_5ff8ad6c0181">
<area shape="poly" alt="Second Dot" coords="256,51,259,48,256,45,253,48"></area>
<area shape="poly" alt="First Dot" coords="183,51,186,48,183,45,180,48"></area>
</map>
</div>
```

The Alt texts ("First dot" and "second dot") show correctly as tooltips when I hover over the areas on the graph when using IE7, but they do not show when using Firefox or IE8.

Any ideas why?

[The example can be seen here](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/334205/test.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The attribute `alt` is only displayed when the the image can not be loaded. Use the `title` attribute instead.

Comment: Some browsers use the `alt` tag if the title isn't present - which is why you are seeing what you are seeing